# Identify columns with all (or almost all) NaN values where target variable is a certain value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, missing-data

What I want to do is identify and drop columns that are missing values where my target variable is = 1. So, I have a toy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,np.nan,5,np.nan,3,5,np.nan], "B":[3,np.nan,2,4,5,4,6,1], 
                   'C': [3,np.nan,np.nan,5,4,np.nan,0,0],"D":[np.nan,np.nan,3,4,4,np.nan,5,6],
                   'target':[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})
```

I figured out how to count the number of missing values in each column and group them by target variable value:

```
c = df.set_index('target').isna().sum(level=0)
```

c dataframe looks like this:

```
       A      B       C       D
target              
0     2.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
1     1.0     1.0     3.0     2.0
```

Here's my problem:

This line of code does not work, apparently "target" is not an actual column name.

```
c.loc[c['target']==1, 'D']
```

I was experimenting with one column to see if it would work. I could just populate an empty list with columns whose missing value count for `'target' = 1` is greater than or equal to 2.

I also tried it by `groupby`, the results are exactly the same:

```
g = df.groupby('target')
g.count().rsub(g.size(), axis=0)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is index, so is possible use `.index` for selecting:

```
print (c.loc[c.index==1, 'D'])
target
1    2.0
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

But better is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by index and column values:

```
print (c.loc[1, 'D'])
2.0
```

If need columns names first get `Series` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and index:

```
s = c.loc[1]
print (s)
A    1.0
B    1.0
C    3.0
D    2.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

And then filter by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) (>=) with `index` values and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (s.index[s.ge(2)].tolist())
#alternative
#print (s[s.ge(2)].index.tolist())
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: That last bit about boolean indexing is helpful, otherwise there is this problem I have run into before: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous